# How to iterate through a google protobuf map in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have my map in the following form:

```
const google::protobuf::Map<string, nrtprofile::RedisNewsMetric> map=redisNewsMessage.ig();
```

How should I iterate through the map to get all the keys and corresponding values?

Comment: Have you read the documentation https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.map?  The map uses standard c++ container patterns.

Comment: There might be another way, I can't check as I don't have Protocol Buffers but looking at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.map), you should be able to get away with something like `for( auto& it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it ) { string key = it->first(); nrtprofile::RedisNewsMetric value = it->second(); }`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I couldn't find any example regarding the implementation in the documentation. It would be helpful if you could provide an example

Comment: what @George said above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You iterate through a `google::protobuf::Map` in exactly the same way as a `std::unordered_map`.

```
for (auto & pair : map)
{
    doSomethingWithKey(pair.first);
    doSomethingWithValue(pair.second);
}
```

If you have a C++17 compiler, you can use a structured binding to split that further

```
for (auto & [key, value] : map)
{
    doSomethingWithKey(key);
    doSomethingWithValue(value);
}
```

Comment: how can a proto map be assigned in cpp?

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated)

> A google::protobuf::Map is a special container type used in protocol buffers to store map fields. As you can see from its interface below, it uses a commonly-used subset of std::map and std::unordered_map methods

and

> google::protobuf::Map supports the same iterator API as std::map and std::unordered_map. If you don't want to use google::protobuf::Map directly, you can convert a google::protobuf::Map to a standard map by doing the following:

So either of the two approaches shown in the example code below should work:

```
int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> mymap;

  mymap['b'] = 100;
  mymap['a'] = 200;
  mymap['c'] = 300;

  // show content:
  for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

  for (auto& x : mymap)
    std::cout << x.first << " => " << x.second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

to be able to do structured binding `for` with protobuf Map:

```
for (auto & [key, value] : map) {
}
```

you need to include this bit of code that tells the compiler to to do it:

```
namespace std {
    template<typename TK, typename TV>
    class tuple_size<google::protobuf::MapPair<TK,TV>> : public std::integral_constant<size_t, 2> { };

    template<size_t I, typename TK, typename TV> 
    struct tuple_element< I, google::protobuf::MapPair<TK, TV>> { };
    template<typename TK, typename TV> struct tuple_element<0, google::protobuf::MapPair<TK, TV>> { using type = TK; };
    template<typename TK, typename TV> struct tuple_element<1, google::protobuf::MapPair<TK, TV>> { using type = TV; };

    template<int I, typename TK, typename TV>
    auto get(const google::protobuf::MapPair<TK, TV>& x) {
        if constexpr (I == 0) return x.first;
        if constexpr (I == 1) return x.second;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow many thanks for this. For whatever compiling iterating on Maps on windows using C++17 fails when using structured binding. This code fixed it for me.

Comment: This is needed in VS2017 but seem to be working out of the box without this in VS2019